# Connect to a lan network from another network

Tags: networking

I have a 2 networks that looks like the below representation:

```
   Client1  ----                                           ------  Client3
(172.10.0.10)  |        (NETWORK1)         (NETWORK2)      |    (172.20.0.10)
               |_______  Gatewway1   _____  Gateway2 ______|  
               |       (172.10.0.1)       (172.20.0.1)     |
   Client2  ----                                           ------   Client4
(172.10.0.11)                                                    (172.20.0.11)
```

The clients can be PC or Linux clients. The gateways are linux servers.
The subnets of both networks are different. Both gateways have their own firewalls, iptables etc.

My question is there any way(like changing ip/gateway settings) by which Client 1/2 without physically relocating to Network 2, be a part of Network 2 such that it behaves like CLient 3/4?

Comment: The short answer is yes.  The long answer could be quite long, and depends on what you mean by "behaves like".   Basically, the firewalls need to pass the relevant traffic.  You may need co-operating DNS or other name servers.  If the gateways are not on the same network you may need a tunnel between them.

Comment: Both network's are in same location?

Comment: @BillThor: By "behaves like" I mean Client 1 should be able to access all the services like web server, file server etc which are accessible only in network 2 . Also it should be able to communicate with other clients in network 2(like if they were in the same LAN)

Comment: @vembutech: Yes, same location, but in different subnets. Client 1 is able to ping Gateway2 but not Client 3.

Comment: In order for two different networks, VLANs to talk to each other, a Layer three device like a L3 switch is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest setup is to establish a full IP range VPN between both networks. Disable any DNS/DHCP servers on Network 1. Finally, just configure Network 1's clients to either use DHCP or manually set the IP settings.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you please describe the setup a bit? I do not have much experience in networking. So can you please provide steps /links for how to implement this for a Windows client and Linux Gateway?